# Need help with regex and negative match in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, regex-negation

I am trying to match a paragraph:

```
<p>content</p>
```

A simple `<p>(.*?)</p>` works, but sometimes that paragraph contains another paragraph inside so my pattern matchs after the first paragraph ends and not until the second one.

The paragraph that causes me the problem looks like this:

```
<p><p><b>something</b></p>content</p>
```

How can I match the main paragraph ignoring the any other p tags inside that one?

I tried

```
<p>(.*?)(?<!</b>)</p>
```

But it didn't work.

I am using preg_match_all php function.

Comment: Why don't you use an HTML parser?

Comment: Because i am working on an existing code with a lot of patterns and this pattern is the only one that is not working, I don't want to recode everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I've needed to deal with situations like this, I've created a recursive function **findClosingTag** that looks for the next closing tag's index (e.g. `</p>`).  If there's another opening tag (e.g. `<p>`) *before* that index, then I recurse and look for the close to that nested start tag.  Continue until you reach the end of the original tag.  Maybe not the most efficient, but probably better than parsing a full DOM if you don't need that.

I don't have the snippet laying around right now, but it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks that seems like a nice solution, I have solved it now using a quick and nasty "hack" with preg_replace and removing the second <p> that was causing problems.

Answer (score 3):

regex is terrible for parsing nested tags. That's why you use a dom or xml parser.

Comment: That's awesome that you're on here! You helped me a lot on PHPFreaks back in the day!

Comment: I'd like to emphasise this. Regex isn't just "terrible" for parsing nested tags. They are incapable of doing it. Regular expressions cannot parse nested structures. They fundamentally, mathematically, provably do not have that power. Also see any of many, many questions on SO where people ask how they can use regex to parse HTML.